# ModelBinders registration in Owin startup.cs

Tags: c#, .net, model-view-controller, owin

I've created a custom model binder for decimals but stuck with a problem. I can't register it via `Global.asax.cs` because I don't have one.

How to make this line work in startup.cs class?

```
ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(decimal), new DecimalModelBinder());
```

Comment: Why not manually add a global.asax file then?

Comment: @Igor because there is no need to do so.

Comment: @DavidL - I prefer cleaner SoC. Model binding code in its own file or method and called directly from the `Application_Start` method in the `Global.asax.cs` file. I would then keep my OWIN startup code in the `startup.cs` file and register it either through the naming convention (default) or with the web.config `owin:appStartup` key.

Answer (score 1):

It will work in an OWIN startup class just fine provided `System.Web.Mvc` is referenced.

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(decimal), new DecimalModelBinder());
    ...
}
```